# SAPUI5 navigation and return

Tags: sapui5

I have 2 views: in master1 I display a list of items and when I click on one item, I navigate to master2. The code in the controller master1.js looks like this:

```
                onSelect : function(oEvent) {
                        this.getRouter().navTo("master2", {
                               from : "master1",
                                zlonr : oLoadingOrder.LoNumber
                                });
                },
```

In master2.js in onRouteMatched I have this code:

```
            onRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
                        var that = this;
                        var oParameters = oEvent.getParameters();

                        if (oParameters.name === "master2") {
                                var oView = this.getView();
                                var oDialog = oView.byId("dialogBaseInfo");

                                if (!oDialog) {

                                oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(),"ZABC.view.fragment.BaseInfo",this);
                                oView.addDependent(oDialog);
                                                    }
                                            this.setCurrentDateTime();
                                            oDialog.open();
```

},

So I am simply opening a dialog.
I can see that the dialog opens, but then it closes again right away but it goes to master2 screen. There is no error in the debugger for it. 
My routing looks like this:

```
                    pattern: "master1",
                    name: "master1",
                    view: "Master1",
    //              viewLevel: 1,
                    targetAggregation: "pages",
                    clearControlAggregation: true,
                    targetControl: "masterAppId",
                    subroutes: [
                    {
                        pattern: "zlonr/{zlonr}",
                        name: "master2",
                        view: "Master2",
        //              viewLevel: 1,
                        targetAggregation: "pages",
```

Any ideas why this happens? The dialog should stay of course open and continue on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but then it closes again right away

By default, the [target handler](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.routing.TargetHandler.html), which is created by the router, automatically closes all dialog instances when navigation occurs. The target handler offers a method to change this behavior with `setCloseDialogs`. Before navigating to "master2", try to add the following line:

```
this.getRouter().getTargetHandler().setCloseDialogs(false);
```

---

For other unexpected behaviors, try to avoid using deprecated properties such as `subroutes`. Instead, use [`targets.yourTargetName.parent`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.routing.Targets.html#constructor). Take a look at [this tutorial step](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/cdab0a1123514cc08cf2c8deb22f312e.html) to see how `parent` can be used. Also `clearControlAggregation` shouldn't be used if there is no `sap.ui.ux3.Shell` in use which [is deprecated](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.ux3.Shell.html) as well.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your comments. It sounds about right, but it still closes the dialog. I tried to put this before navigating to the master2 and also tried to put it in the init of the master2 but still closes the dialog.

Comment: @Tim: I see. It would be nice if you could post some more codes or a minimal example somewhere where we could reproduce the problem. Otherwise you could debug through call stacks to find out which method call from which module destroys (or closes) the dialog.

Comment: thanks again for your help. I have changed my setup a little, not calling the dialog right after navigating. could not find another way to solve this. thanks anyways for your help!